# How can I update multiple columns in sequelize.query

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

For now I update my table `accounts` with `accountId` and it's working perfectly.

```
return models.sequelize.query("UPDATE \"accounts\" " +
                                        "SET \"accountId\" = "+newAccount.id+" " +
                                        "WHERE \"accountId\" = "+oldAccount.id+";").spread(function(){
            return 'success';
        });
```

What if I want to change not only accountId, but, say, the date.
How should I write it then? I've tried writing it with the comma

`"SET \"accountId\" = "+ newAccount.id+",\"date\" + newAccount.date + " WHERE...`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Appreciate your help.

UPDATE: in console I get this message
`[2015-10-25 16:42:00.909] [TRACE] main - Executing (default): UPDATE "accounts" SET "date" = Sun Oct 25 2015 16:42:00 GMT+0300 (MSK) WHERE "date" = Sun Oct 25 2015 16:41:53 GMT+0300 (MSK);` but after that I don't get any 'success' message (data didn't change in db). May it happen because of data type? I have 'timestamp with time zone' in my postgresql database.

I guess, [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4307) can be the same problem

Comment: I think you missed one = after date. "SET \"accountId\" = "+ newAccount.id+ ",\"date\" =" + newAccount.date + " WHERE...

Comment: @MajidYaghouti updated the code, but no changes. In fact now I have this string `UPDATE "accounts" SET "accountId" = (new_value), "date" = (new_value) WHERE "accountId" = (value), "date" = (value);`, but it doesn't work at all: even accountID doesn't update.

Comment: Remember to use binds, otherwise you may be vulnerable to SQLi attacks! e.g. `query("UPDATE a SET b = :id", {replacements: {id: "123"}});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to query by a date, you are sending over a JavaScript date object which gets converted into a string of the local time.  PostgreSQL then rejects this due to invalid syntax both because the date doesn't get quoted and because it won't recognize the format.

Whenever possible, try not use raw queries when using Sequelize, because Sequelize can do all of the necessary serialization and deserialization for you.  Your some issue could easily be done by writing this:

```
var Account = sequelize.define('account', {
  accountId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  date: Sequelize.DATE
});

Account.update({
  accountId: newAccount.id,
  date: new Date()
}, {
  where: {
    accountId: oldAccount.id
  }
}).then(function() {
  callback('success');
});
```

If you really want to do this with a raw query, you should convert your date object into something that PostgreSQL can read.  You could do this with the moment library for instance:

```
var moment = require('moment');

models.sequelize.query("UPDATE \"accounts\" " +
 "SET \"accountId\" = " + newAccount.id + ", " +
   "\"date\" = '" + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + "' " +
 "WHERE \"accountId\" = " + oldAccount.id + ";").spread(function(){
 return 'success';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but in postgres logs I found this error:`2015-10-26 19:51:54 MSK ERROR:  syntax error at or near "43" at character 55
2015-10-26 19:51:54 MSK STATEMENT:  UPDATE "accounts" SET "date" = 2015-10-26 23:40:45.363+03 WHERE "date" = 2015-10-26 19:40:45.363+03;`

Comment: Assuming that in db 'date' column you will see something like this`"2015-10-26 20:33:02.255+03"`

Comment: You're forgetting to quote the date.

Comment: Thanks for help and patience!

Comment: Remember to use binds, otherwise you may be vulnerable to SQLi attacks! e.g. `query("UPDATE a SET b = :id", {replacements: {id: "123"}});`